# amplify-gradle-config.json (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: android, aws-amplify

i was trying to use AWS amplify facilities with my android app. my gradle is failed to build with an error showing.
this is my app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.azuretest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core:0.9.0'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-api:0.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

this is my project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.60'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.amplifyframework:amplify-tools-gradle-plugin:0.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.amplifyframework.amplifytools'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is the error:
F:\AzureTest\amplify-gradle-config.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
Note: I'm totally new on this platform, I'm sorry if I violate the protocols of asking question.

Answer (score 0):

You must have missed a step while you were following creating the app. Refer to **Step 3.** in the following document:

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start

1. For **part a.** regarding `amplify configure`, make sure to run that in your app's root directory. (in your case F:\AzureTest)
2. Make sure to perform **part b.** in your Android Studio toolbar as well

Comment: I have same issue. 
The issue occurred when I was trying to do **Step1 c. Run ‘Make Project’**.
Therefore  it doesn't add the gradle task **amplifyPush**.

I can't try **Step 3 part b** 

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start#step-1-configure-your-app